# How to automatically run an app as administrator and make its UI visible to non-admin users under Windows 8

Tags: windows, windows-8, boot, administrator, windows-task-scheduler

I have found many examples of how to get apps to automatically start and run (without UAC prompting), but have not managed to find one that allows the app's UI to be visible to a non-admin account.  The closest I have gotten to success is using Task Scheduler to start an app either using /ONSTART or /ONLOGON.  I can see the app's process in the Task Manager but it's UI is not visible to the user.  It's system tray icon isn't visible either.

How can I get the add to run as administrator yet still be completely usable by any user account?

Comment: Can you turn off UAC?

Comment: I'm sorry I forgot to mention that, but for this case I cannot completely disable UAC.  It may be possible, however, to disable UAC for just this app.  Is that possible?

Comment: I would argue that if you are not allowed to disable UAC, then you should not try to work around it.  It serves an important security function and disabling it for even one app begins to weaken the security of the system.

Comment: I cannot completely disable UAC for everything, but I can turn it off for this particular app if Windows 8 support it.  Otherwise, I need to re-write my application so that the port that requires elevated (admin) status runs hidden from the end user and uses inter-process communication to send data to the non-elevated UI portion of the app.

Comment: this is not possible. You must rewrite the app.

Comment: I have re-written my app so that the admin portion broadcasts UDP packets to the client, but if the admin portion is started via Task Scheduler the client never gets the broadcasts.  What could possibly be the problem?